# how to avoid call afterSave for particular function execute in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

how to avoid call afterSave for particular function execute in cakephp

in model i having

public function afterSave() { 
}

every time insert record manually using forms i need to call afterSave()...

but when i insert record using for loop. i dont want to call afterSave()....

my for loop code is

```
if(count($properties)>0) {

        foreach($properties as $key => $value) {

            $ppinsertdata = array(
                            'id' => '',
                            'property_id' => $value,
                            'plan_id' => ConstPropertyPlan::Free,
                            'is_expired' => 0,
                            'expiry_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$duration days",time()))
                        );

            $this->PropertyPlan->save($ppinsertdata);
            $pplastinsertid = $this->PropertyPlan->getLastInsertID();

            $updateproperty['id'] = $key;
            $updateproperty['property_plan_id'] = $pplastinsertid;
            $updateproperty['plan_id'] = ConstPropertyPlan::Free;
            $this->Property->save($updateproperty);

        }
    }
```

i got error this line $this->PropertyPlan->save($ppinsertdata);

how to avoid to call afterSave() in this scenario

Pls help me to solve this solution....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
 $this->PropertyPlan->save($ppinsertdata, array('callbacks' => false)); //for disabling all callbacks
```

Read This -

`callbacks Set to false to disable callbacks. Using ‘before’ or ‘after’ will enable only those callbacks`

[save()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array) - cakephp

Comment: Try to avoid using queries inside loops. Use `saveMany()` or `saveAll` instead. :)